# Changing the title of a button inside a custom cell of my tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view, inside which there is a cell. This cell has a button which is declared like this in the customTableVIewCell class.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

inside the table view controller, i am setting method for this button.

```
[cell.myButton setTitle:@"Show cell number!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

i want to change the title of the button whenever it is selected.

Now consider this:
I have three cells in my table view, that is my table has three rows.
In each row, there is a button called myButton.

Whenever it is clicked, i want to change the title of the button to 1 or 2 or 3 depending on the cell number in which the button exists.

i tried this:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonClicked:(id)sender{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.tableVIew indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]];
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"button was clicked for the following row %i", row);
}
```

But this is printing "button was clicked for the following row 0" to the console, no matter the button on cell #1 or cell #2 or cell #3 were clicked. (cell is nothing but the table row)

Please help me.

Comment: Are you working with indexPath.row or indexPath.section? How many rows do you return on UITableViewDataSource delegate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method cellForRowAtIndexPath where you initialise the cell,add this

```
cell.myButton.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And update your myButtonClicked method.

```
- (IBAction)myButtonClicked:(id)sender{
 UIButton *btn=sender;
NSLog(@"button was clicked for the following row %i", btn.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting button tag as-

```
cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row;
```

in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method..

And in your myButtonClicked method get the tag of sender button.. and then do whatever you want to do further.

```
- (IBAction)myButtonClicked:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"button was clicked for the following row %i", sender.tag);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the sender in the IBAction :)

```
- (IBAction)myButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
    [sender setTitle:@"show new title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```